# Add Native Android UnityPlayer in react-native application resulting in black screen

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, react-native, native

Resolved! Read my answer.

I'm trying to display a Unity view in a native React application. This UnityPlayer shows the camera feed for AR with Vuforia. We need to include this view in a React-native application for iOS and Android.

I followed many guides but I have a black screen in the Android version.
If I run UnityPlayerActivity (from the Android project exported by Unity) in the Android project generated by react-native (instead of ReactActivity), I see my UnityPlayer correctly. So I guess my project contains all the necessary dependencies.

Code snippet of my js code :

```
const UnityIosContainerView = requireNativeComponent("UnityContainerView",
null);
const UnityAndroidContainerView = requireNativeComponent("RCT3DView", null);

class ArPage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "red" }}>
       {Platform.OS === "ios" ? (
         <UnityIosContainerView style={{ flex: 1 }} />
        ) : (
         <UnityAndroidContainerView style={{ flex: 1 }} />
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Following this guide [https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-android.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/judHr.png)
I have a custom package

```
 public class CustomReactPackage implements ReactPackage {
  @Override
  public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    return Collections.emptyList();
  }

  @Override
  public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    return Arrays.<ViewManager>asList(
      new React3DViewManager()
    );
  }
}
```

And here is my ViewManager connected to the lifetime of the MainReactActivity to manage correctly the UnityPlayer

```
public class React3DViewManager extends SimpleViewManager<View> implements LifecycleEventListener {

  public static final String REACT_CLASS = "RCT3DView";

  private UnityPlayer mUnityPlayer;

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return REACT_CLASS;
  }

  @Override
  protected View createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext reactContext) {

    reactContext.addLifecycleEventListener(this);
    mUnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer(reactContext);
    int glesMode = mUnityPlayer.getSettings().getInt("gles_mode", 1);
    boolean trueColor8888 = false;
    mUnityPlayer.init(glesMode, trueColor8888);
    mUnityPlayer.start();
    mUnityPlayer.requestFocus();

    return mUnityPlayer.getView();
  }

  @Override
  public void onHostResume() {
    mUnityPlayer.resume();
  }

  @Override
  public void onHostPause() {
   mUnityPlayer.pause();
  }

  @Override
  public void onHostDestroy() {
    mUnityPlayer.quit();
  }
}
```

The resulting screenshot:

[image]

Validated points:

- Show a Native ImageView works.
- Show a simple GLSurfaceView works.
- Try to launch UnityPlayerActivity instead of ReactActivity to valid if all requirements are presents in the Android project. All works properly.
- Try to embedded UnityPlayer in a Custom Native View has no effect.
- Connect UnityPlayer to the activity lifetime (in the ViewManager) has no effect, even if the lifetime events are invoked.

Unity 2017.2.0f3

React 16.0.0.0-alpha12

React-native 0.48.4

Has anyone ever encountered this problem?

Application log:

```
01-05 13:39:27.142 7233-7240/? I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
01-05 13:39:27.156 7233-7233/? W/ActivityThread: Application com.protoreactnative is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
01-05 13:39:27.156 7233-7233/? I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
01-05 13:39:29.228 7233-7240/com.protoreactnative I/art: Debugger is active
01-05 13:39:29.365 7233-7233/com.protoreactnative I/System.out: Debugger has connected
01-05 13:39:29.365 7233-7233/com.protoreactnative I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
01-05 13:39:29.567 7233-7233/com.protoreactnative I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
01-05 13:39:29.768 7233-7233/com.protoreactnative I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
01-05 13:39:29.970 7233-7233/com.protoreactnative I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
01-05 13:39:30.171 7233-7233/com.protoreactnative I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
01-05 13:39:30.372 7233-7233/com.protoreactnative I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
01-05 13:39:30.573 7233-7233/com.protoreactnative I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
01-05 13:39:30.775 7233-7233/com.protoreactnative I/System.out: debugger has settled (1451)
01-05 13:39:31.131 7233-7233/com.protoreactnative I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
01-05 13:39:31.142 7233-7233/com.protoreactnative V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: locked dso store /data/user/0/com.protoreactnative/lib-main
01-05 13:39:31.143 7233-7233/com.protoreactnative I/fb-UnpackingSoSource: dso store is up-to-date: /data/user/0/com.protoreactnative/lib-main
01-05 13:39:31.143 7233-7233/com.protoreactnative V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: releasing dso store lock for /data/user/0/com.protoreactnative/lib-main
01-05 13:39:31.217 7233-7240/com.protoreactnative I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
01-05 13:39:31.222 7233-7233/com.protoreactnative D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.ctor()
01-05 13:39:31.272 7233-7233/com.protoreactnative D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
01-05 13:39:31.292 7233-7233/com.protoreactnative I/SensorManager: registerListenerImpl: listener = com.facebook.react.common.ShakeDetector@f6f1ff2, sensor = {Sensor name="Accelerometer Sensor", vendor="hTC Corp.", version=1, type=1, maxRange=39.2266, resolution=0.01, power=0.17, minDelay=10000}, delay = 66667, handler = null
01-05 13:39:31.315 7233-7233/com.protoreactnative D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContextInBackground()
01-05 13:39:31.316 7233-7233/com.protoreactnative D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackgroundInner()
01-05 13:39:31.318 7233-7233/com.protoreactnative D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.onJSBundleLoadedFromServer()
01-05 13:39:31.321 7233-7233/com.protoreactnative D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackground()
01-05 13:39:31.321 7233-7233/com.protoreactnative D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.runCreateReactContextOnNewThread()
01-05 13:39:31.359 7233-7254/com.protoreactnative I/art: Thread[15,tid=7254,Native,Thread*=0xf2e86b00,peer=0x12dcf280,"Thread-4"] recursive attempt to load library "/data/app/com.protoreactnative-2/lib/arm/libfb.so"
01-05 13:39:31.364 7233-7254/com.protoreactnative D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext()
01-05 13:39:31.394 7233-7233/com.protoreactnative W/unknown:ReactNative: Packager connection already open, nooping.
01-05 13:39:31.396 7233-7258/com.protoreactnative D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornetcontext+,hn 9(0x6c6f63616c686f),sn(),hints(known),family 0,flags 1024, proc=com.protoreactnative
01-05 13:39:31.396 7233-7255/com.protoreactnative D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornetcontext+,hn 9(0x6c6f63616c686f),sn(),hints(known),family 0,flags 1024, proc=com.protoreactnative
01-05 13:39:31.396 7233-7257/com.protoreactnative D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornetcontext+,hn 9(0x6c6f63616c686f),sn(),hints(known),family 0,flags 1024, proc=com.protoreactnative
01-05 13:39:31.397 7233-7257/com.protoreactnative D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfo_proxy get netid:0
01-05 13:39:31.397 7233-7255/com.protoreactnative D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfo_proxy get netid:0
01-05 13:39:31.399 7233-7255/com.protoreactnative D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfo_proxy-, success
01-05 13:39:31.401 7233-7257/com.protoreactnative D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfo_proxy-, success
01-05 13:39:31.402 7233-7258/com.protoreactnative D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfo_proxy get netid:0
01-05 13:39:31.403 7233-7258/com.protoreactnative D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfo_proxy-, success
01-05 13:39:31.411 7233-7257/com.protoreactnative W/unknown:InspectorPackagerConnection: Couldn't connect to packager, will silently retry
01-05 13:39:31.457 7233-7254/com.protoreactnative W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTGroupViewManager
01-05 13:39:31.467 7233-7262/com.protoreactnative I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : b756f35, I9267f384df
                                                            Build Date                       : 10/19/16
                                                            OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.09.00.03
                                                            Local Branch                     : 
                                                            Remote Branch                    : refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF64.1.2.3_RB1.07.00.00.258.005
                                                            Remote Branch                    : NONE
                                                            Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
01-05 13:39:31.467 7233-7254/com.protoreactnative W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTGroupShadowNode
01-05 13:39:31.489 7233-7254/com.protoreactnative W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTShapeViewManager
01-05 13:39:31.490 7233-7254/com.protoreactnative W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTShapeShadowNode
01-05 13:39:31.503 7233-7254/com.protoreactnative W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTTextViewManager
01-05 13:39:31.504 7233-7254/com.protoreactnative W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTTextShadowNode
01-05 13:39:31.509 7233-7254/com.protoreactnative W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.checkbox.ReactCheckBoxManager
01-05 13:39:31.540 7233-7254/com.protoreactnative W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.uimanager.LayoutShadowNode
01-05 13:39:31.589 7233-7254/com.protoreactnative W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.picker.ReactDialogPickerManager
01-05 13:39:31.600 7233-7254/com.protoreactnative W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.drawer.ReactDrawerLayoutManager
01-05 13:39:31.608 7233-7254/com.protoreactnative W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.picker.ReactDropdownPickerManager
01-05 13:39:31.612 7233-7254/com.protoreactnative W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.scroll.ReactHorizontalScrollViewManager
01-05 13:39:31.631 7233-7254/com.protoreactnative W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.scroll.ReactHorizontalScrollContainerViewManager
01-05 13:39:31.635 7233-7254/com.protoreactnative W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.progressbar.ReactProgressBarViewManager
01-05 13:39:31.641 7233-7254/com.protoreactnative W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.progressbar.ProgressBarShadowNode
01-05 13:39:31.646 7233-7254/com.protoreactnative W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.scroll.ReactScrollViewManager
01-05 13:39:31.659 7233-7254/com.protoreactnative W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.slider.ReactSliderManager
01-05 13:39:31.665 7233-7254/com.protoreactnative W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.slider.ReactSliderManager$ReactSliderShadowNode
01-05 13:39:31.669 7233-7254/com.protoreactnative W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.switchview.ReactSwitchManager
01-05 13:39:31.672 7233-7254/com.protoreactnative W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.switchview.ReactSwitchManager$ReactSwitchShadowNode
01-05 13:39:31.676 7233-7254/com.protoreactnative W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.toolbar.ReactToolbarManager
01-05 13:39:31.683 7233-7254/com.protoreactnative W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.webview.ReactWebViewManager
01-05 13:39:31.692 7233-7254/com.protoreactnative W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.swiperefresh.SwipeRefreshLayoutManager
01-05 13:39:31.697 7233-7254/com.protoreactnative W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTSurfaceViewManager
01-05 13:39:31.699 7233-7254/com.protoreactnative W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTSurfaceViewShadowNode
01-05 13:39:31.704 7233-7254/com.protoreactnative W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.frescosupport.FrescoBasedReactTextInlineImageViewManager
01-05 13:39:31.705 7233-7254/com.protoreactnative W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.frescosupport.FrescoBasedReactTextInlineImageShadowNode
01-05 13:39:31.711 7233-7254/com.protoreactnative W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.image.ReactImageManager
01-05 13:39:31.720 7233-7254/com.protoreactnative W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.modal.ReactModalHostManager
01-05 13:39:31.723 7233-7254/com.protoreactnative W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.modal.ModalHostShadowNode
01-05 13:39:31.725 7233-7254/com.protoreactnative W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactRawTextManager
01-05 13:39:31.726 7233-7254/com.protoreactnative W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactRawTextShadowNode
01-05 13:39:31.728 7233-7254/com.protoreactnative W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.textinput.ReactTextInputManager
01-05 13:39:31.746 7233-7254/com.protoreactnative W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.textinput.ReactTextInputShadowNode
01-05 13:39:31.757 7233-7254/com.protoreactnative W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactTextViewManager
01-05 13:39:31.764 7233-7254/com.protoreactnative W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactTextShadowNode
01-05 13:39:31.768 7233-7254/com.protoreactnative W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewManager
01-05 13:39:31.778 7233-7254/com.protoreactnative W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.viewpager.ReactViewPagerManager
01-05 13:39:31.782 7233-7254/com.protoreactnative W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactVirtualTextViewManager
01-05 13:39:31.783 7233-7254/com.protoreactnative W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactVirtualTextShadowNode
01-05 13:39:31.785 7233-7254/com.protoreactnative W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.protoreactnative.react.React3DViewManager
01-05 13:39:31.844 7233-7254/com.protoreactnative D/ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge.
01-05 13:39:31.849 7233-7254/com.protoreactnative D/ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge before initializeBridge
01-05 13:39:31.863 7233-7254/com.protoreactnative D/ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge after initializeBridge
01-05 13:39:31.863 7233-7254/com.protoreactnative D/ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle()
01-05 13:39:31.864 7233-7270/com.protoreactnative D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.setupReactContext()
01-05 13:39:31.864 7233-7270/com.protoreactnative D/ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.initialize()
01-05 13:39:31.866 7233-7270/com.protoreactnative W/unknown:ReactNative: Packager connection already open, nooping.
01-05 13:39:31.871 7233-7270/com.protoreactnative D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.attachRootViewToInstance()
01-05 13:39:32.249 7233-7270/com.protoreactnative I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.android.chrome version 62.0.3202.84 (code 320208452)
01-05 13:39:32.293 7233-7270/com.protoreactnative I/cr_LibraryLoader: Time to load native libraries: 6 ms (timestamps 2695-2701)
01-05 13:39:32.311 7233-7270/com.protoreactnative I/chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(46)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
01-05 13:39:32.313 7233-7270/com.protoreactnative I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "62.0.3202.84", actual native library version number "62.0.3202.84"
01-05 13:39:32.467 7233-7237/com.protoreactnative I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=31KB, data=30KB
01-05 13:39:32.467 7233-7237/com.protoreactnative I/art: After code cache collection, code=30KB, data=29KB
01-05 13:39:32.467 7233-7237/com.protoreactnative I/art: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
01-05 13:39:32.692 7233-7269/com.protoreactnative I/ReactNativeJS: Running application "protoreactnative" with appParams: {"rootTag":1}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF
01-05 13:40:29.776 7233-7233/com.protoreactnative I/Unity: onResume
01-05 13:40:29.797 7233-7257/com.protoreactnative D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornetcontext+,hn 9(0x6c6f63616c686f),sn(),hints(known),family 0,flags 1024, proc=com.protoreactnative
01-05 13:40:29.797 7233-7257/com.protoreactnative D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfo_proxy get netid:0
01-05 13:40:29.799 7233-7257/com.protoreactnative D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfo_proxy-, success
01-05 13:40:29.827 7233-7233/com.protoreactnative D/Unity: SetWindow 0 0xe3b38e08
01-05 13:40:29.827 7233-7233/com.protoreactnative D/Unity: SetWindow 0 0xe3b38e08
01-05 13:40:31.871 7233-7257/com.protoreactnative D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornetcontext+,hn 9(0x6c6f63616c686f),sn(),hints(known),family 0,flags 1024, proc=com.protoreactnative
01-05 13:40:31.872 7233-7257/com.protoreactnative D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfo_proxy get netid:0
01-05 13:40:31.881 7233-7257/com.protoreactnative D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfo_proxy-, success
```

Comment: Please add a Unity log.

Comment: A little log:01-05 11:07:19.604 24714-24714/com.protoreactnative D/Unity: SetWindow 0 0xe3b38e08
When a run UnityPlayerACtivity a have a full log. But now.... nothing...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For more information, all are describe Here :
[Part 1](https://medium.com/@beaulieufrancois/show-unity3d-view-in-react-native-application-yes-its-possible-852923389f2d)
[Part 2](https://medium.com/@beaulieufrancois/part-2-show-unity3d-view-in-react-native-application-138219323cbc)

Ok after many tries I found the solution. 
It's very important to connect UnityPlayer to all Lifetime of the MainActivity. The ViewManager class doesn't support all activity lifetime. You can just connect the manager to Resume, pause and destroy. But UnityPlayer requires onConfigurationChanged to ensure the layout will be correct. I take the code directly from the class UnityPlayerActivity generated by Unity and I expose the UnityPlayer for usage in the ViewManager.

Here is my MainActivity with the UnityPlayer init.

```
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

  private UnityPlayer mUnityPlayer;

  public UnityPlayer getUnityPlayer() {
    return mUnityPlayer;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBX_8888); // <--- This makes xperia play happy
    mUnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer(this);
  }

  public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mUnityPlayer.quit();

  }

  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mUnityPlayer.resume();

  }

  /**
   * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
   * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
   */
  @Override
  protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "protoreactnative";
  }

  // Low Memory Unity
  @Override public void onLowMemory()
  {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mUnityPlayer.lowMemory();
  }

  // Trim Memory Unity
  @Override public void onTrimMemory(int level)
  {
    super.onTrimMemory(level);
    if (level == TRIM_MEMORY_RUNNING_CRITICAL)
    {
      mUnityPlayer.lowMemory();
    }
  }

  // This ensures the layout will be correct.
  @Override public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
  {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mUnityPlayer.configurationChanged(newConfig);
  }

  // Notify Unity of the focus change.
  @Override public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
  {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    mUnityPlayer.windowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
  }

  // For some reason the multiple keyevent type is not supported by the ndk.
  // Force event injection by overriding dispatchKeyEvent().
  @Override public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)
  {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_MULTIPLE)
      return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event);
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
  }

  // Pass any events not handled by (unfocused) views straight to UnityPlayer
  @Override public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)     { return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event); }
  @Override public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)   { return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event); }
  @Override public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)          { return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event); }
  /*API12*/ public boolean onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent event)  { return mUnityPlayer.injectEvent(event); }
}
```

Here is the view manager :

```
public class React3DViewManager extends SimpleViewManager<UnityPlayer>  {

  public static final String REACT_CLASS = "RCT3DView";

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return REACT_CLASS;
  }

  @Override
  protected UnityPlayer createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext reactContext) {
    MainActivity activity = (MainActivity)reactContext.getCurrentActivity();
    return activity.getUnityPlayer();
  }
}
```

I don't know if this solution is the best solution, but this solution works properly for my needs.

Thanks

Comment: This might also be useful for those who want to do the same but on iOS: https://gist.github.com/fortinmike/fbb055d8e22dd4c2424dea871bb5da73

Comment: Awesome job dude. Is there any way you can contribute to https://github.com/f111fei/react-native-unity-view. I do not maintain the package, but a lot of people have the same issue as you described here.